# Why does setSelection method not work in onLoadFinished?

Tags: android

I want to set selection in my ListFragment  in onLoadFinished method, but Log.v(TAG, " onLoadFinished: Selected id -> " + getSelectedItemId()); line returns onLoadFinished: Selected id -> -9223372036854775808 ?

What is the issues?

```
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<LoaderResult> loader, LoaderResult data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data.cursor);

    // The list should now be shown.
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
    if (data.cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        setSelection(0);
        Log.v(TAG, " onLoadFinished: Selected id -> " + getSelectedItemId());
    }        
}
```

Thanks!